# How to get all related_name fields in django with serializers?

Tags: python, django

here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my seralizers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Sum,Avg,Max,Min,Count,F,Q

class CatalogSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    dynamic_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_dynamic_data(self, obj):
        totalpieces = Catalog.objects.all().aggregate(total_pieces=Count('no_of_pcs'))
        totalprice = Catalog.objects.all().aggregate(total_price=Sum('per_piece_price'))
        return totalprice,totalpieces

class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'catalog','user')

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    company_name = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
```

here is my view.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse

from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets


class CatalogView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Catalog.objects.select_related('company_name')
    serializer_class = CatalogSerializer

class CompanyView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Company.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CompanySerializer

class UserView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from api import views
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('catalogs',views.CatalogView)
router.register('companies',views.CompanyView)
router.register('users',views.UserView)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

when i will go
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/companies/

m getting

```
     [
        {
            "name": "google",
            "phone_number": 12,
            "catalog": [
                5
            ]
        }
    ]
```

m expecting this..

```
     [
        {
            "url": "google",
            "name": "google",
            "phone_number": 123214214,
            "catalog_details":[
                "name": "sobhagya",
                "no_of_pcs": 22,
                "per_piece_price": "3567.00",
            ]
        }
    ]
```

here I am able to get only id of `related_name` which i have set as `foreignkKey` but I expect all the fields like this above..
please check the json api formats

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class CompanySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    catalog = CatalogSerializer(many=True) # if you want many catalog objects connected to the company else many=False
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'catalog','user')
```

you need to call the catalog serializer inside of the company serializer to get the related objects

Comment: Yes you are right, but i don't want all fields . i want specific fields. there is total 4 fields. i want 3

Comment: as you are using fields='__all__' it will render all the fields.

Comment: fields = ('name', 'phone_number', 'catalog','user')

Comment: m using like this

Comment: no not in company serializer, in catalog serializer. you need to mention only the function name, and the field names you need