# How can i make my serializer more dynamic

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Catalog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    no_of_pcs = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    per_piece_price = models.DecimalField(null=True,blank=True,max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    company_name = models.ForeignKey(Company,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='catalog')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

here is my serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Sum,Count

class CatalogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    total_pieces = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    total_price = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Catalog
        fields = ('name','no_of_pcs','per_piece_price','company_name','total_pieces','total_price')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super(CatalogSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        rep['company'] = {
                              "company_name":instance.company_name.name,
                              "phone_number":instance.company_name.phone_number,
                              "company_id":instance.company_name.id
                         }
        return rep

    def get_total_pieces(self, obj):
        totalpieces = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_pieces=Count('no_of_pcs'))
        return totalpieces["total_pieces"]

    def get_total_price(self, obj):
        totalprice = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_price=Sum('per_piece_price'))
        return totalprice["total_price"]
```

here is my views.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
import json
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from .serializers import *
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework import viewsets

class CatalogView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset =  Catalog.objects.select_related('company_name')
    serializer_class = CatalogSerializer
```

How can i make my serializers more dynamic instead of doing manually(rough way).
is there any better way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all related\_name fields in django with serializers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467339/how-to-get-all-related-name-fields-in-django-with-serializers)

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `serializerMethodField(**kwargs)` field it calculates total_pieces and total_price for every item, it means when there are 100 items it sends query to calculate 200 times. To avoid this I advice you to add extra `action` or using `list_route`(for older version of rest framework) decorators. You will call this api when you need this kind of statistics.
Example:

```
class CatalogView(ModelViewSet):
    @list_route(['GET'], permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny])
    def get_statistics(self, request):
        result = Catalog.objects.aggregate(total_pieces=Sum('no_of_pc'), total_price=Sum('per_piece_price')) # it returns dictionary such as {'total_pieces': 10, 'total_price': 1200}
        return Response(results)
```